# Weird simulation output

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I have the following code (which is an extract on something I'm currently working on):

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_min_example is
end entity tb_min_example;

architecture arch of tb_min_example is
    signal clk1, clk2, slow_clk : std_logic;

    signal y : std_logic;

    procedure drive_clk(signal clk : out std_logic; constant period : time) is
    begin
        loop
            clk <= '1';
            wait for period / 2;
            clk <= '0';
            wait for period / 2;
        end loop;
    end procedure drive_clk;
begin

    drive_clk(clk1, period => 4 ns);
    drive_clk(slow_clk, period => (119.0 / 8.0) * 4 ns);
    clk2 <= clk1;

    process(slow_clk) is
    begin
        if rising_edge(slow_clk) then
            y <= clk1 xor clk2;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture arch;
```

I would expect the signal `y` to be low all the time since `clk2` is assigned to `clk1` and `x xor x == 1`. However, I'm seeing this strange waveform:
[image]

It seems that `clk2` (or `clk1`) is sampled just a bit earlier than the other and therefore the result of `clk2 xor clk1` is not zero. Why is that, is there some weird delta-cycle stuff going on?

I'm using XSim with Vivado version 2020.2

Comment: You are sampling a faster signal with a way slower clock, I know this is simulation but you are not respecting the Shannon sampling theorem here.

Comment: Also, this is a recipe for a metastable design.

Comment: And lastly, it's discouraged to do logic operations on clocks (at least for FPGA designs, which is what you are doing because of the Vivado tag). If you need to do operations on clocks, use the dedicated MMCM

Comment: This does not answer my question. I only included the tag `vivado` because I'm currently using xsim (for which there is no tag). Nowhere did I suggest (or am I planing to) use the design from above for any real firmware.

Comment: And indeed I commented, not answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clk2` is a delayed version of `clk1` - delayed by 1 simulation delta cycle.
Because `slow_clk` and `clk1` rise at the same time initially, they will always be in sync on every 2 `slow_clk` rising edges (119/8 = 59.5, and hence they are both related clocks and align every 2nd rising edge of `slow_clk`). At this point, clk1 will be '1' while clk2 will be '0', giving you the XOR result of '1'.

This is generally why re-assigning clocks in a design can cause you simulation problems.

If you simply delay the start of `slow_clock` you should see `y` being always '0'.